Logistic regression only cares about the $E[X|Y]$ for prediction
I was reading this blogpost about how logistic regression and Naive Bayes with gaussian features are equivalent
This led me to think that at the end of the day, logistic regression only cares about the difference in $E[X|Y]$ for the various classes
Indeed, in the equivalence is assumed that  $Var[X|Y=y]=\sigma^2,\, \forall y \in Y$, and thus if $E[X|Y=y]=\mu,\, \forall y \in Y$, then $P(X|Y)=P(X)$, since they are assumed to be gaussian
However, I can't quite get the math to show this; in particular, I would like to see mathematically that, no matter what are the underlying distribution of the various features $P(X|Y)$, we need $E[X|Y=0] \neq E[X|Y=1]$ for the logistic regression to "use" such feature
After that, given that inequality holds, ideally, the significance should depend on the variance of such features, even without the assumption of $P(X|Y)$ to be Gaussian (since it seems to be something not necessary for such models, What are the myths associated with linear regression, data transformations?)
I'm pretty sure that this has to do with statistical testing, central limit theorem, and some very fundamental theorem in statistics, but I can't quite wrap my head around that right now, any help?

Sketch of some sort of a proof (coauthored by LLMs...):
the log likelyhood function is $l(\beta_0, \beta) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( y_i (\beta_0 + \beta x_i) - \log(1 + e^{\beta_0 + \beta x_i}) \right)$
its gradient is $\frac{\partial l(\beta_0, \beta)}{\partial \beta} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( y_i x_i - \frac{x_i e^{\beta_0 + \beta x_i}}{1 + e^{\beta_0 + \beta x_i}} \right)$
which simplified leads to $\frac{\partial l(\beta_0, \beta)}{\partial \beta} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( y_i x_i - x_i \sigma(\beta_0 + \beta x_i) \right)$
Taking the expectation on both sides wrt the data distribution we get:
$$
E\left[\frac{\partial l(\beta_0, \beta)}{\partial \beta}\right] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( E[y_i x_i] - E[x_i \sigma(\beta_0 + \beta x_i)] \right)
$$
At this point, let's assume that $\beta = 0$ (thus that feature is ignored by the model)

for the first term, we use the law of total expectation, and we get $E[y_i x_i] = E[Y] c$
for the second term, again using LTE, $E[x_i \sigma(\beta_0 + \beta x_i)] = E[E[x_i \sigma(\beta_0 + \beta 0) | Y]]$, and since $E[X | Y] = c$, we have:
$$
E[x_i \sigma(\beta_0 + \beta 0) | Y = y] = c \sigma(\beta_0)
$$

Combining everything we get:
$$
E\left[\frac{\partial l(\beta_0, \beta)}{\partial \beta}\right] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( E[Y] c - c E[\sigma(\beta_0)] \right)
$$
Therefore, if f $E[Y] = E[\sigma(\beta_0)]$, $\beta = 0$ is a valid solution, and we can conclude that the model will just predict the average $Y$, proving that if $E[X|Y=y]=c,\,\,\forall y \in Y$, then the logistic regression model can't use such feature for prediction

There seems to be some internal contradiction in this post, because logistic regression has nothing to do with the Gaussian distribution you reference at the end.  Are you sure you are even asking about logistic regression?

@whuber that was just to specify that i didn't want to use such assumption in the proof

@whuber I see your point though... in the meantime, I've added a sketch of proof for what I was saying, though I can't really figure out how to prove that the marginal has different expectations, the predictive power is defined by the variance of the marginals, at least not without assuming the features being gaussian (assumption that I would not really love to do, as stated in that last part... since I'd use the equivalence between naive bayes and LR to show it)
